# Sorting Dictionary in a lexicographical order and applying MD5 encryption

Tags: c#, .net, hash-map

I'm sorting a Dictionary in a lexicographical order and applying MD5 encryption. I would like to wrap the sorting somewhere inside the encryption method or so.

- Official Java example - [here](https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/Java/src/main/java/com/mexc/example/spot/websocket/MexcSpotRawWsExample.java#L84-L90)
- [Docs](https://github.com/mxcdevelop/APIDoc/blob/master/websocket/spot/websocket.2022_2_28.md#%E8%8E%B7%E5%8F%96%E8%B4%A6%E6%88%B7%E8%AE%A2%E5%8D%95%E7%8A%B6%E6%80%81%E6%8E%A8%E9%80%81-get-account-order-status-push)

````cs
private static string GenerateSign(Dictionary<string, object> query, string apiSecret)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var queryParameterString = string.Join("&",
        query.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Value.ToString()))
            .Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString())}"));
    sb.Append(queryParameterString);

    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        sb.Append('&');
    }

    sb.Append("api_secret=").Append(apiSecret);

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static string Sign(string source)
{
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
}

public ValueTask SubscribeToPrivateAsync()
{
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    var @params = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "api_key", _apiKey },
        { "req_time", now },
        { "op", "sub.personal" }
    };

    var javaSorted = @params.OrderBy(item => item.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
        .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);

    var signature = Sign(GenerateSign(javaSorted, _apiSecret));

    var request = new PersonalRequest("sub.personal", _apiKey, signature, now);
    return SendAsync(request);
}

private ValueTask SendAsync<TRequest>(TRequest request)
    where TRequest : SocketRequest
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    return _websocketClient.SendAsync(message);
}
```
````

Comment: is there a reason to assign `api_secret` separately ? why wasn't passed within the dictionary like the others ?

Comment: @isR5, that's the way their API works. You can take a look at the Java code. https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/Java/src/main/java/com/mexc/example/spot/websocket/MexcSpotRawWsExample.java#L126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `MD5` hashing, I would suggest making it an extension method, if it's going to be used outside this scope, however, if it's only used in this class, you can keep it as is, and if it's only going to be used only for this payload, then you can put it inside the `GenerateSign` method. Also, you can use `Convert.ToHexString` instead of `BitConverter.ToString`.

this part :

```
var @params = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "api_key", _apiKey },
    { "req_time", now },
    { "op", "sub.personal" }
};

var javaSorted = @params.OrderBy(item => item.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

can be simplified by using `SortedDictionary<string, object>`, so it would be something like this :

```
var @params = new SortedDictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
{
    { "api_key", _apiKey },
    { "req_time", now },
    { "op", "sub.personal" }
};
// the dictionary is sorted, and ready to use
```

in `GenerateSign`, `Join`, `LINQ`, and `StringBuilder` are mixed, it's fine, but we can add more readability to it and also add some micro-improvements, by simply use `foreach` and a `StringBuilder`. something like this :

```
private static string GenerateSign(IDictionary<string, object> items, string apiSecret)
{
    if (items?.Count == 0) return null;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiSecret)) return null;

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        var key = item.Key;

        var value = item.Value?.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            if (builder.Length > 0)
            {
                builder.Append('&');
            }

            builder.Append($"{key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)}");
        }
    }

    builder.Append("&api_secret=").Append(apiSecret);

    // hash the payload
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
    return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

There is another option here, which I found it feasable, since the payload (from the documentation) is small, and fixed length.

this is the request payload example:

```
{
  "op":"sub.personal",
  "api_key": "api_key",
  "sign": "b8d2ff6432798ef858782d7fd109ab41",
  "req_time": "1561433613583"
}
```

if this is going to have the same object length and order, then how about implementing a class model for it, instead of dictionary ? and use `JsonProperty` attribute to set the key name and order.

Example with **Json.NET** :

```
public class MexcSubPersonalPayload
{
    private readonly string _apiSecret; 

    [JsonProperty("op", Order = 1)]
    public string Operation => "sub.personal";

    [JsonProperty("api_key", Order = 2)]
    public string ApiKey { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("sign", Order = 3)]
    public string Signature => Sign(this.ToString());

    [JsonProperty("req_time", Order = 4)]
    public long RequestTime => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

    private string Sign(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) return null;
        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    public MexcSubPersonalPayload(string apiKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        _apiSecret = apiSecret;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"api_key={ApiKey}&req_time={RequestTime}&op={Operation}&api_secret={_apiSecret}";
    }

}
```

Example with **System.Text.Json**:

```
public class MexcSubPersonalPayload
{
    private readonly string _apiSecret; 

    [JsonPropertyName("op")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
    public string Operation => "sub.personal";

    [JsonPropertyName("api_key")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
    public string ApiKey { get; private set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("sign")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(3)]
    public string Signature => Sign(this.ToString());

    [JsonPropertyName("req_time")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(4)]
    public long RequestTime => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

    private string Sign(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) return null;
        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    public MexcSubPersonalPayload(string apiKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        _apiSecret = apiSecret;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"api_key={ApiKey}&req_time={RequestTime}&op={Operation}&api_secret={_apiSecret}";
    }

}
```

I don't see a need for using `UrlEncode` in this model, as the values will be always valid, except for `api_key` and `_apiSecret`, if they have invalid characters, then you might use `UrlEncode` in them, but I don't know if is it going to invalidate the keys (public and private keys) or the service provider would handle the escaped characters (in this case it won't invalidate them).

anyhow, using the above model, you would only need to pass the public and private keys, and then convert it to JSON.

usage with **Json.NET**

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MexcSubPersonalPayload("api_key", "api_secret"));
```

usage with **System.Text.Json**

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MexcSubPersonalPayload("api_key", "api_secret"));
```

**UPDATE FROM THE COMMENTS**

Combine `javaSorted` with `GenerateSign`

```
private static string GenerateSign(IDictionary<string, object> items, string apiSecret)
{
    if (items?.Count == 0) return null;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiSecret)) return null;

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in items.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value?.ToString())).OrderBy(x => x.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal))
    {
        var key = item.Key;

        var value = item.Value.ToString();

        if (builder.Length > 0)
        {
            builder.Append('&');
        }

        builder.Append($"{key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)}");
    }

    builder.Append("&api_secret=").Append(apiSecret);

    //hash the payload
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
    return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't know there was `Convert.ToHexString`. Actually the lexicographical order `javaSorted` would be nice if it's inside the `GenerateSign` if you know a way

Comment: Something is also wrong with your `GenerateSign`, it returns `{"channel":"sub.personal","msg":"signature validation failed"}`. It previously worked fine `{"channel":"sub.personal","msg":"OK"}`

Comment: One more thing I'm using `System.Text.Json` not Json.Net

Comment: @nop the `GenerateSign` was missing `&` from the `api_secret=`. It's fixed now, it should give you the same results as the original. I'll update my answer with `System.Text.Json` and also put the `javaSorted` inside the `GenerateSign`

Comment: @nop check the update.

Comment: thanks for the update! I like ur approach, however it results into `{"op":"sub.personal","api_key":"xxxxxxxx","sign":"0EFC1CDC2B6EA83DFD6781E7828191C1","req_time":1655035520245}`, which is not lexicographically sorted and leads to an invalid signature.

Comment: I don't get it. I manually changed the `JsonPropertyOrder` to specifically be `{"api_key":"mx0ETo1oU5o7v6M7dH","sign":"89407BDEBD36ACAC6DC63B46C6A3B32C","req_time":1655036830583,"op":"sub.personal"}` to match the previous code and it still says the signature is invalid.

Comment: @nop from the mexc examples, I can see that `secretKey` and `sign` are lowered case,  if they are case sensitive, then we should use `ToLowerInvariant()` on them to ensure that it will always send with a lowered case.

Comment: I changed it to `ToLowerInvariant`, but it is the same. What's not in their documentation is the lexicographical order, which Java does by default. That's what's needed, I contacted their support.

Comment: @nop try change the order from  `StringComparer.Ordinal` to `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Comment: `StringComparer.Ordinal` works fine. The problem is with ur code. It doesn't really have `StringComparer.Ordinal` anywhere. I'm talking about `MexcSubPersonalPayload`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realized that you wanted to accomplish what they did in their Go example. Here is a working code: https://pastebin.com/qtVpMjhc. I just had to change what's in `ToString`. Here is the Go code: https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/go/ws/private/privateWs.go#L35

Comment: @nop glad you've figured it out, and I've mentioned before that you can use `UrlEncode` with the api_key and _apiSecret if they're required to be escaped. perhaps, they are required to be escaped after all.

Comment: thanks, I put `UrlEncode` for both of them just in case.